# How can I get my prompt(); to call my function AND give it an argument?

Tags: javascript, function, alert, prompt, console.log

I'm doing a challenge that had me make a days/weeks/month calculator until you're 90.

I finished it but I can only call the function by calling it in the console like this `lifeInWeeks(25);` I used 25 since that's my age.

But I want to know how can I do this and have a prompt pop up and ask what their age is and then give an alert with the answer, but for this to happen the prompt would have to **call the function and give it input** from **the answer** i.e. the **prompt should call the function** and **the answer of that prompt should be the function's argument.**

Something like this:

> "What is your age?" (you answer) 25

Then an alert pops up and says:

> "You have 23725 days, 3380 weeks, and 780 months left."

WITHOUT having to manually call the function in the console like this: `lifeInWeeks(25);`

Here's my code:

```
function lifeInWeeks(age) {
    var days = (90 - age) * 365;
    var weeks = (90 - age) * 52;
    var months = (90 - age) * 12;
    alert("You have " + days + " days, " + weeks + " weeks, and " + months + " months left.");

}

lifeInWeeks(25);
```

I've tried putting the prompt inside the function but that hasn't worked, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put prompt user for entering age, and then use then value from user input

```js
let life = prompt("What is your age ?")
lifeInWeeks(+life);

function lifeInWeeks(age) {
    var days = (90 - age) * 365;
    var weeks = (90 - age) * 52;
    var months = (90 - age) * 12;
    alert("You have " + days + " days, " + weeks + " weeks, and " + months + " months left.");

}
```

You can also move this inside function, in that case you need to invoke the function without any parameter

Comment: Ah perfect this worked like a charm thank you. I haven't learned yet that you can give an argument like that. It's kind of like a form of concatenation in a way. Interesting, thank you!